# Toggle Buttons in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, button, toggle, powerpoint

I am trying to insert toggle buttons into several pages on a powerpoint. I've got the buttons to behave the way I want, but now I can't see to do two things:

A. Run the program!!! I've deleted everything and started from scratch, except for my first code (see below) and have nothing else written. What do I need to fix it. When I click on the shape that is connected to YourName() nothing happens.

B. I'd like to set the buttons' values to 0 at the start. Once this runs, do you think my code will do that?

Thanks

```
Sub YourName()
Dim userName As String
Dim ToggleButton1 As ToggleButton
Dim ToggleButton2 As ToggleButton
Dim ToggleButton3 As ToggleButton
Dim ToggleButton4 As ToggleButton
Dim done As Boolean

done = False
While Not done
userName = InputBox(Prompt:="My name is", Title:="Input Name")
   If userName = "" Then
    done = False
Else
    done = True
End If
Wend

FeedbackAnswered = False

ActivePresentation.Slides(2).ToggleButton("ToggleButton1").Value = 0
ActivePresentation.Slides(2).ToggleButton("ToggleButton2").Value = 0
ActivePresentation.Slides(2).ToggleButton("ToggleButton3").Value = 0
ActivePresentation.Slides(2).ToggleButton("ToggleButton4").Value = 0


ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't compile (open the IDE, open the module the code's in, choose Debug | Compile).  When you try to run broken code within a slide show (as it seems you're doing) PPT doesn't issue any error messages, it just won't attempt to run the code at all.

This at least compiles; I didn't have time to create a presentation with the correct shapes but hey, had to leave SOME of the fun for you:

```
Option Explicit

Sub YourName()
Dim userName As String

' Dim these as Object; there's no such thing as ToggleButton
Dim ToggleButton1 As Object
Dim ToggleButton2 As Object
Dim ToggleButton3 As Object
Dim ToggleButton4 As Object
Dim done As Boolean
' You forgot one:
Dim FeedbackAnswered As Boolean

done = False
While Not done
userName = InputBox(Prompt:="My name is", Title:="Input Name")
   If userName = "" Then
    done = False
```

' you might want to add an Exit Sub here, otherwise the poor
' user has no way out

```
Else
    done = True
End If
Wend

FeedbackAnswered = False

' Fixed these too:
ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("ToggleButton1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 0
ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("ToggleButton2").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 0
ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("ToggleButton3").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 0
ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("ToggleButton4").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 0


ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next

End Sub
```